# OLEObject label not displaying when executing Word macro from Powershell

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I have a Word macro that insert an Excel (.xlsx) document somewhere in it (at a bookmark).

When i execute this macro from Word, everyting work as intented.
When I launch the same macro with Powershell, the document (or many documents ...) is inserted but without label.

If i do a right click / object / convert on the object, i can see that the label is there. I f i quit with "Ok" without doing any modification, the label is visible.

Powershell code that execute the Word Mmacro :

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$document = $word.Documents.Open("$path\myfile.docm")
$document.Application.Run("InsertXLSX")
$document.save()
$document.SaveAs2("$path\myfile.docx", [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatDocumentDefault)
$document.Close()
$word.Quit()
```

Macro code (VBA, simplified for the example) :

```
Sub InsertXLSX()
    Dim path As String
    path = "..."
    Dim ExcelPath As String
    Dim IconPath As String
    ExcelPath = path + "\Data\xlsx\"
    IconPath = path + "\Data\excel.ico"
    
    bookmark= "toto"

    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
    FileName:=ExcelPath + bookmark + ".xlsx", _
    ClassType:="Excel.Sheet", _
    DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
    IconIndex:=0, _
    IconFileName:=IconPath, _
    IconLabel:=bookmark, _
    Range:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmark).Range

    Set selectionRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank's

Edit :

I tried to reach the same goal but with only Powershell, without the Word macro.
Same problem.

Powershell code :

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$document = $word.Documents.Open("pathtofolder\docfile.docx")

$ClassType     = "Excel.Sheet"
$FileName      = "pathtofolder\clsxfile.xlsx"
$LinkToFile    = $False
$DisplayAsIcon = $True
$IconFileName  = "pathtofolder\icone.ico"
$IconIndex     = 19 # or 0 or 1 or whatever
$IconLabel     = "this is the label"

$oleObject = $document.Bookmarks.Item("mybookmark").range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject($ClassType,$FileName,$LinkToFile,$DisplayAsIcon,$IconFileName,$IconIndex,$IconLabel)

$document.Save()
$word.Quit()
```

Result in a simple Word document :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well,
I found out that only the first oleObject created will have the label not displayed when using the full powershell version (without macro).
To correct that, I create a "trash" ole object and then delete it so my other ole object that are added works fine.

Here's the code i added to create and delete the trash ole object :

```
$ClassTypeDel     = "Excel.Sheet"
$FileNameDel      = "arandomfile.txt"
$LinkToFileDel    = $False
$DisplayAsIconDel = $True
$IconFileNameDel  = "arandomicon.ico"
$IconIndexDel     = 1
$IconLabelDel     = "aaaaa"
$oleObjectDel = $document.Bookmarks.Item("aaaaa").range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject($ClassTypeDel,$FileNameDel,$LinkToFileDel,$DisplayAsIconDel,$IconFileNameDel,$IconIndexDel,$IconLabelDel)
$oleObjectDel.Delete()
$document.Bookmarks.Item("aaaaa").Delete()
```